# Is this bad practice for inserting data into db?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function that inserts data from a checkbox into my sql database and it works just find, but Im pretty new to this so I would like to know if there is a better/safer (from sql injections) way to do this. I know I should be using PDO with prepared statements, but that is something I am tackling later.

Here is the form that produces the html checkboxes:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
    if(empty($clients) === true){   
    echo '<p>You do not have any clients yet.</p>';
    }
    else
    {
    foreach($clients as $client){
    echo'
        <input type="checkbox"  name="client_data[]" value="'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'|'.$class_id.'|'.$client['first_name'].'|'.$client['nickname'].'|'.$client['last_name'].'">
        '.$client['first_name'].' ('.$client['nickname'].') '.$client['last_name'].'
         <br />';


   } // foreach($client

} // if empty 

?>
```

Here is the php that calls the function:

```
if (isset($_POST['exist_to_class'])){
if (empty($_POST['client_data']) === true){
    $errors [] = 'You much select a client to be added to the class.';
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['client_data']) && !empty($_POST['client_data']));
    foreach ($_POST['client_data'] as $cd){
     exist_client_to_class($cd);
     header('Location: view_class.php?class_id='.$class_id.' ');

} // foreach $cd

} // else

} //isset
```

And here is my function that inserts the data into the db:

```
// add existing client to class  ----------------------------------------------------
function exist_client_to_class($cd){

list($user_id, $class_id, $first_name, $last_name, $nickname) = explode('|', $cd);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `clients` (user_id, class_id, first_name, last_name, nickname, date) 
            VALUES('$user_id', '$class_id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$nickname', CURDATE())");

}
```

First stab at a PDO prepared statement:**UPDATE**

```
function exist_client_to_class($cd){

try{

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO clients 
(user_id, class_id, first_name, last_name, nickname, date)
VALUES (:user_id, :class_id, :first_name, :last_name, :nickname, CURDATE())
');

list($user_id, $class_id, $first_name, $last_name, $nickname) = explode('|', $cd);

$stmt->execute(array(
        ':user_id' => $user_id, 
        ':class_id' => $class_id, 
        ':first_name' => $first_name,
        ':last_name' => $last_name,
        ':nickname' => $nickname
        )
        );
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

}
```

Here is the db connect file:

```
//PDO database connect
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=customn7_cm', '**********', '**********');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Yes, very unsafe. Why not look into PDO right now? It is easy to learn prepared statements and you learn it the right way

Comment: +1 for suggesting PDO instead of this attempt.

Comment: PHP Data Objects : PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. Force yourself to track it now. I changed my life with it start now.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples, and http://bobby-tables.com/ gives links to articles that explain exactly why you need to start using PDO and prepared statements now.

Comment: an evil user could send a request containing postdata: `user_id='); DROP TABLE clients;#`

Comment: It's not only PDO guys. http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php and the note `Apart from the feature list, I suggest you try out both MySQLi and PDO and find out what API design you like most. MySQLi is more powerful and probably more complex to learn. PDO is more elegant and has the advantage that you only need to learn one PHP API if you need to work with different DBMS in the future.`

Answer (score 2):

To put simply, Yes.

You aren't sanitizing or escaping your user data in anyway.  you are using the old `mysql_*` community deprecated functions.  You're best bet is to start using `PDO` or `Mysqli`

Read this article: [PHP Database Access: Are You Doing It Correctly?](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/?search_index=2)

Comment: Yes, not escaping the values spliced into an SQL command is a really bad idea - I might have voted this answer up were it not for the fact you failed to notice that Colbyd does exactly the same thing with values spliced into the HTML - making the code susceptible to stored XSS

Comment: PHP without a framework can be a minefield. I'm still not sure why people insist on building their own applications from the ground up on the standard library.

Comment: @Colbyd Sounds good, good luck,  if you have any questions post them on here and I'll hit you back.

Comment: You've got it backwards. A good framework will teach you how to use PHP properly.

Comment: @bigman I added my first attempt above, not getting any errors. Can you tell me what wrong about this...probably most of it.

Comment: [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) and [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/) are all worth checking out. Find one that suits your style and you'll be a lot more productive. At the very least, use a PHP database library like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org) to clean up your database access code.

Comment: @Colbyd ORM's are great, but you first need to understand how to create normalized schemas.  I don't recommend Cake, purely for performance (it's the worst), Kohana or Fuel are great options.

Comment: @bigman I added my attempt at PDO above. Can you tell me what I have done wrong here?

Comment: @Colbyd  in `execute` it needs to be an array.  So you can either do the `list()` outside of the execute statement and create an array, `array(':user_id' => $user_id, ':class_id' => $class_id`

Comment: @bigman updated query above...dont think i did it right because its still not working.

Comment: @Colbyd ok for curdate, don't do it like that.  take it out of execute, that entire line.  You have too many variables.  Also, on your PDO instance, set it to handle exceptions (it's in the article i linked) that way you can output the errors you are getting to help debug

Comment: @bigman I posted my db connect file above. I believe I have it set to handle exceptions, but not getting any errors and still not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19596/discussion-between-colbyd-and-bigman)

Comment: @Colbyd remove this `':date'     => CURDATE()` but leave the end `)`  you should also turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` Also put a space after `VALUES`, it might think its a function.

Comment: @bigman code above is updated, I have had error_reporting(E_ALL); set in my `init.php` which has all my includes for db connections and my function files. Firebug gives me a 500 Internal Server Error but the browser itself does not output any errors.

Comment: @bigman I just did a `var_dump ($conn)` inside my function and it returned `NULL` `$conn` is the variable assigned in my PDO connection. Does they shed any light on the problem?

Comment: @Colbyd ya, your connection might be having issues.  Looks over it,

Comment: @bigman the only way I know to test this is by changing something in the username or password which when I do throws an error. I would assume if I enter correct user/pass it will connect and no errors will be thrown? Is there something else I need to look at to ensure its connecting? I do have a `mysql_connect` db connection open as well do you think that could cause the problem. I cant really test this as all my app function are mysql and entire app will not work if I take this connection out.

Comment: @Colbyd at this point, check your error logs, something is awry.

Comment: @bigman very strange nothing showing up in errors logs from server in the last couple of days

Answer (score 1):

This works for most sql injections:                     (from [php.net](http://www.php.net)) 
decleration:
string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

```
       // Connect
       $link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password') OR die(mysql_error());
        // Query
        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($user),
        mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

Comment: `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. Even thinking about using it is a bad idea.